# Getting a build error in Unity3d when building a VR project

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I am trying to build a sample project which can be found at this link https://www.coursera.org/learn/xr-introduction/supplement/cARor/project-work-build-a-vr-application-to-your-device and I am getting this error:
Build completed with a result of 'Failed'
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun()

UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 4 errors

at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x00242] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:194

at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x0007f] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:97 
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun()

What to do?

Comment: Try to build in a different location? Preferably outside your project folder.

Comment: Also post a screenshot of errors and XR settings from Player settings.

Comment: Thanks, man it works changing the location of the build apk.

Comment: You should make this as an answer dude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to build in a different location? Preferably outside your project folder.